# Adicionar title rato

Tags: javascript

Estou a utilizar um ficheiro externo raphael.js para criar um gráfico circular. Utilizei como fonte esta página: https://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/creating-a-svg-pie-chart-html5/

Queria adicionar um title, ao passar com o rato com o seu valor.

Exemplo do código:  http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não irá rodar no jsfiddle, pois o caminho `http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/3/js/raphael.js` não existe.

No lado esquerdo do jsfiddle há a opção de adicionar frameworks já predefinidos.
http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/4/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Para aparecer um valor quando passar o mouse você pode colocar um atributo title.

Logo depois de:
        arc.attr("fill", color[i]);
        arc.attr("title", "Valor: "+data[i]);
http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/9/